# Match the route with params by react-router v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Have a couple of routes with params (like. /user/:user,  car/:car/:year) 
I'm trying to avoid to manually parse `location.pathname` if it's possible to use react-router (v3) for it.

How can I find the route that match to the current url location. 
Need something similar to:

```
if (router.match_to_route('/user/:user')) {
   ... do something
}
...
```

The method matchRoutes in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/modules/matchRoutes.js might be the one that I need.
Thanks.

Updated:

It can be achieved by

```
import { match } from 'react-router';

const routes = router.routes;
match({ routes, location }, (error, redirect, renderProps) => {
   const listOfMatchingRoutes = renderProps.routes;
   if (listOfMatchingRoutes.some(route => route.path === '/user/:user')) {
      ...
   }
}
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3312#issuecomment-299450079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this using react-router-dom. I simplified the code so that you can easily understand it. I just passed the param user with my dashboard route in main App component and access it using **this.props.match.params.user** in my child component named as Dashboard.

**App.js file**

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
    this.state = {message: "StackOverflow"};
  }

render(){
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>

            <Route exact path="/dashboard/:user" render={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
            <Route exact path="/information" render={props => <Information {...props} />} />
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
 }
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React from 'react';


class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
            <div ><h1> Hello {this.props.match.params.user}</h1></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Dear Rohit,  your answer is correct. Unfortunately is not applicable to the problem I'm trying to solve. Thanks

Comment: Ok @DraganS, No problem

Answer (score 1):

On RR4 you can use [matchPath](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md)

```
const match =  routes.find(route) => matchPath(props.location.pathname, {
    path: route.path,
    exact: true,
    strict: false
  })
```